# Excel Conditional Formatting Sometimes Applying

Tags: excel-2010, conditional-formatting

I am trying to apply a condition that highlights a cell that is outside of an entered number range. I also need to have any non-numeric values not get highlighted because of this. Initially I had my conditions set as Any cell value not between
    `=$AJ$1 and =$AJ$2` applying to the range `=$AJ$7:$AJ$3000`
This highlighted any non-numeric cells, so I also applied the condition `=ISTEXT(AJ7:AJ3000)` to clear out any formatting. Together and separate, these conditions aren't behaving at all like I thought; occasionally highlighting non-numeric cells, and only some values outside of the specified range.

Hopefully the screenshot provides enough clarity in the matter and there is a way to fix this very confusing issue.
[image]
*(Sorry about the selective blurring. They're just section headers.)*

Comment: You say you are using `ISTEXT(AJ7:AJ3000)` in your question but in the view from image with conditional formating it says `ISTEXT(AJ1...)`? You sure your formula in the conditional is correct?

Comment: Yes I am. Sorry, I spaced out that it cuts off the formula. The formula is `=ISTEXT(AJ1:AJ3000)`

Answer (score 0):

`ISTEXT` is a single cell test. That is, it tests if a given cell contains text. While it will work for you over a range that is not the default defined behavior of it.

Using `ISTEXT(AJ1:AJ3000)` will cause all kinds of problems for conditional formatting. When viewing conditional formatting it applies to the cell you have selected. In the image it is AJ1. The formulas should also reflect that. So in that cell you should have `ISTEXT(AJ1)`. The `Applies to` area then fixes the remaining part of the formula an applies to cell you are working with.

That should fix you problem.

Comment: I have tried your suggestion but to no avail. Every time I apply a condition, I have the entire column highlighted. In this picture [link](http://pasteboard.co/70emElf1K.png) I have an expanded version of the formats. Now for _some reason_ it works absolutely perfectly. But when I replicate the exact same procedure on another column it doesn't work. Either cells within the range highlight, or random ones highlight when the top 2 cells are left blank. Is there another way to go about doing this that I should look into?

Comment: @bonzo First the formulas in conditional formatting always apply when true so the =true isn't needed. Your formulas are still `=ISTEXT(AJ7:AJ3000)` so did you try setting the formula to `=ISTEXT(AJ7)`? By having the range with AJ7:AJ3000 you usually get fairly random behavior.  Conditional formatting is also as you might have noticed the most counter intuitive thing in Excel

Comment: Yeah so I always thought that `=TRUE` was a little odd, but I found it in another thread and figured the guy knew more about it than me and decided to keep it in. Removing it has caused no changes. I did change the formula over to `=ISTEXT(AJ7)` and saw no change. The same errors occur when the range cells are left blank (all non zero numbers highlight), so it doesn't seem to be that.
For now, I everything works fine if a range is always in the cells by default. I'll see if there's a way to have them auto fill in when left blank. I know it's a band-aid solution however.

Comment: @bonzo Weird. Tested it out myself and all of it works as intended for me. Could try `=AND(ISNUMBER(AJ7);NOT(AJ7<$AJ$1);NOT(AJ7>$AJ$2))` into the rule at AJ7 (Make sure you have AJ7 selected when you edit that is) as the only formula, does the same as the two tests you are using, but if you are having issues with the other part this probably causes the same problems.

Comment: I just wanted to give a final update on this and the currently working solution so this isn't left hanging. To keep computations at a minimum (really to lower the chance of one of the users accidentally deleting an equation), I have my conditional formats looking at hidden cells, IF the AJ1 and AJ2 cells are left blank. Those hidden cells have predetermined ranges in them that I know the data values won't exceed. Will post code if anyone (future or otherwise) is interested.

Comment: @Bonzo Ohh, maybe I misunderstood, you were having issues when there were no values in the AJ1 and AJ2 fields and if that was the case you wanted nothing to get highligthed? Let me know and I'll fix the answer to work with that

Answer (score 0):

The OP is barely comprehensible, if at all, but assuming:

> Highlight Column AJ cells from Row7 downwards, if containing `0` or `1`

then I suggest select ColumnAJ and HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=AND(OR(AJ1=0,AJ1=1),ROW()>6,NOT(ISBLANK(AJ1)))
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, select colour Fill (highlight) of your choice, <kbd>OK</kbd>, <kbd>OK</kbd>.

Comment: Thank you for your help and input. I am sorry if my post is not up to the highest of standards that you seem to be living. May I suggest you direct message me so as to educate me in the ways of crafting such miraculous posts in your eyes?
Now that that's out of the way, I have already tried that actually and still found no results. I figure it is more of a quirk of excel and decided to take a more tedious (but efficient) approach at fixing this.